# F# parse log with multiline entries

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm parsing log files (entries starting with debug/warning/info) in a line-by-line manner and have encountered rare occurrences where a single log entry spans multiple lines - eg, the warning here:

```
debug: Preparing movie /movies/menu_background.sfd: 272204
info: /init
debug: Playing movie c:\program files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\supreme commander forged alliance\movies\menu_background.sfd: 272204
warning: Error running OnDestroy script in Entity bsa0001 at 2f8b6908: ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): attempt to call method `Destroy' (a nil value)
         stack traceback:
            ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): in function <...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua:5489>
            ...orever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\units\mobileunit.lua(65): in function `DestroyAllTrashBags'
```

My current code is below - which ignores the additional lines (puts them in misclist) - is not what I want. I would like to amend the code to include the additional lines with the prior info/warning/debug entry. My C# brain can do this procedurally but I'm trying to do this in a more functional manner as I learn F#.

```
let rec sortLines (lines: string list) (warninglist: string list) (debuglist: string list) (infolist: string list) (misclist: string list) : string list list =
    match lines with
    | (h::t) when h.StartsWith("debug") ->
        sortLines t warninglist (h :: debuglist) infolist misclist
    | (h::t) when h.StartsWith("info") ->
        sortLines t warninglist debuglist (h :: infolist) misclist
    | (h::t) when h.StartsWith("warning") ->
        sortLines t (h :: warninglist) debuglist infolist misclist
    | (h::t) ->
        sortLines t warninglist debuglist infolist (h :: misclist)
    | [] ->
        [warninglist; debuglist; infolist; misclist]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to maintain state while iterating through a collection, `fold` is often your friend. I would suggest a solution like this:

```ml
type Log =
    {
        Info : List<string>
        Debug : List<string>
        Warning : List<string>
    }

module Log =

    let empty =
        {
            Info = []
            Debug = []
            Warning = []
        }

    let logInfo line log =
        { log with Info = line :: log.Info }

    let logDebug line log =
        { log with Debug = line :: log.Debug }

    let logWarning line log =
        { log with Warning = line :: log.Warning }

    let logInvalid line log =
        failwith "Invalid state"

    let read lines =
        let log, _ =
            Seq.fold (fun (log, logger) (line : string) ->
                let logger' =
                    if line.StartsWith("info") then logInfo
                    elif line.StartsWith("debug") then logDebug
                    elif line.StartsWith("warning") then logWarning
                    else logger
                let log' = logger' line log
                log', logger') (empty, logInvalid) lines
        log
```

The `read` function loops through the incoming lines, assigning each one to its correct level. `log` is the current state of the log, and `logger` is a function that will add a single line to the log.

If you prefer recursion, here's an equivalent implementation:

```ml
    let read lines =
        
        let rec loop log logger lines =
            match lines with
                | (line : string) :: tail ->
                    let logger' =
                        if line.StartsWith("info") then logInfo
                        elif line.StartsWith("debug") then logDebug
                        elif line.StartsWith("warning") then logWarning
                        else logger
                    let log' = logger' line log
                    loop log' logger' tail
                | [] -> log

        loop empty logInvalid lines
```

You can test it like this:

```ml
let lines =
    [
        @"debug: Preparing movie /movies/menu_background.sfd: 272204"
        @"info: /init"
        @"debug: Playing movie c:\program files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\supreme commander forged alliance\movies\menu_background.sfd: 272204"
        @"warning: Error running OnDestroy script in Entity bsa0001 at 2f8b6908: ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): attempt to call method `Destroy' (a nil value)"
        @"         stack traceback:"
        @"            ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): in function <...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua:5489>"
        @"            ...orever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\units\mobileunit.lua(65): in function `DestroyAllTrashBags'"
    ]

let log = Log.read lines
printfn "Info:"; for line in List.rev log.Info do printfn "   %s" line
printfn "Debug:"; for line in List.rev log.Debug do printfn "   %s" line
printfn "Warning:"; for line in List.rev log.Warning do printfn "   %s" line
```

Output is:

```
Info:
   info: /init
Debug:
   debug: Preparing movie /movies/menu_background.sfd: 272204
   debug: Playing movie c:\program files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\supreme commander forged alliance\movies\menu_background.sfd: 272204
Warning:
   warning: Error running OnDestroy script in Entity bsa0001 at 2f8b6908: ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): attempt to call method `Destroy' (a nil value)
            stack traceback:
               ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): in function <...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua:5489>
               ...orever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\units\mobileunit.lua(65): in function `DestroyAllTrashBags'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution that solves the immediate problem:

```
open System

let toWarningString lines =
    lines |> List.rev |> String.concat Environment.NewLine

let rec consumeWarning acc (lines : string list) =
    match acc, lines with
    | [], h::t when h.StartsWith"warning" ->
        consumeWarning (h :: acc) t
    | _, h::_ when h.StartsWith "debug" -> lines, toWarningString acc
    | _, h::_ when h.StartsWith "info" -> lines, toWarningString acc
    | _, [] -> lines, toWarningString acc
    | _, h::t -> consumeWarning (h :: acc) t


let rec sortLines (lines: string list) (warninglist: string list) (debuglist: string list) (infolist: string list) (misclist: string list) : string list list =
    match lines with
    | (h::t) when h.StartsWith("debug") ->
        sortLines t warninglist (h :: debuglist) infolist misclist
    | (h::t) when h.StartsWith("info") ->
        sortLines t warninglist debuglist (h :: infolist) misclist
    | (h::t) when h.StartsWith("warning") ->
        let rest, warning = consumeWarning [] (h :: t)
        sortLines rest (warning :: warninglist) debuglist infolist misclist
    | (h::t) ->
        sortLines t warninglist debuglist infolist (h :: misclist)
    | [] ->
        [warninglist; debuglist; infolist; misclist]
```

That said, [Brian Berns is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835899/126014) that there are more principled ways to address problems like this. The reason I still post the above code is that it may meet you at the right place in your learning journey... Maybe.

One could definitely trot out the Writer or State monad to make this syntactically much nicer.

Another option is to look into *parser combinators*, although that's likely overkill for something like this.

Those alternatives would require essentially throwing away everything already here, so perhaps the above can serve as an interim solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another quick and dirty POC based on regex.
Mapping the log to tuples makes them easy to work with.

```
let log = """
debug: Preparing movie /movies/menu_background.sfd: 272204
info: /init
debug: Playing movie c:\program files (x86)\steam\steamapps\common\supreme commander forged alliance\movies\menu_background.sfd: 272204
warning: Error running OnDestroy script in Entity bsa0001 at 2f8b6908: ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): attempt to call method `Destroy' (a nil value)
         stack traceback:
            ...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua(5494): in function <...gramdata\faforever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\unit.lua:5489>
            ...orever\gamedata\lua.nx2\lua\sim\units\mobileunit.lua(65): in function `DestroyAllTrashBags'
"""

let regex = new Regex(@"((info|warning|debug): ((.*?)+)(?=[\r\n]?(?:info|warning|debug|$)))+", RegexOptions.Singleline)
let matches = log |> regex.Matches

let mappedLog = matches |> Seq.cast<Match> |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x.Groups[2].Value, x.Groups[3].Value))
printf "mappedLog: %A\n\n" mappedLog

let filteredMap = mappedLog |> Seq.filter (fun (x:string,_) -> x = "debug")    
printf "filteredMap: %A\n\n" filteredMap
```